# Cannot seem to figure out this regex involving forward slash

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I am trying to capture instances in my dataframe where a string has the following format:

`/random a/random b/random c/capture this/random again/random/random`

Where a string is preceded by four instances of `/`, and more than two `/` appear after it, I would like the string captured and returned in a different column. If it is not applicable to that row, return `None`.

In this instance `capture this` should be captured and placed into a new column.

This is what I tried:

```
def extract_special_string(df, column):
    df['special_string_a'] = df[column].apply(lambda x: re.search(r'(?<=\/{4})[^\/]+(?=\/[^\/]{2,})', x).group(0) if re.search(r'(?<=\/{4})[^\/]+(?=\/[^\/]{2,})', x) else None)

extract_special_string(df, 'column')
```

However nothing is being captured. Can anybody help with this regex? Thanks.

Comment: FYI you don't need to escape `/` in python. It has to be escaped in languages that use `/` as the regexp delimiter, but in Python they're just ordinary strings.

Comment: `/{4}` matches `////` all together. Not `/foo/bar/baz/x/`

Comment: I know you're asking about regex, but you could also split the string at `/` and take the 5th element of the resulting list if its length is >= 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
df['special_string_a'] = df[column].str.extract(r'^(?:[^/]*/){4}([^/]+)(?:/[^/]*){2}', expand=False)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sM1c5G/1)

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^/]*/){4}` - four occurrences of any zero or more chars other than `/` and then a `/` char
- `([^/]+)` - Capturing group 1:one or more chars other than a `/` char
- `(?:/[^/]*){2}` - two occurrences of a `/` char and then any zero or more chars other than `/`.

Answer (score -2):

An alternative regex approach would be to use *non-greedy quantifiers*.

```py
import re
s = '/random a/random b/random c/capture this/random again/random/random'
pattern = r'/(?:.*?/){3}(.*?)(?:/.*?){2,}'
m = re.match(pattern, s)
print(m.group(1))  # 'capture this'
```

- `/(?:.*?/){3}` - match the part before `capture this`, matching any but *as few as possible* characters between each pair of `/`s (use noncapturing group to ignore the contents)
- `(.*?)` - capture `capture this` (since this is a capturing group, we can fetch the contents from `<match_object>.group(1)`
- `(?:/.*?){2,}` - same as the first part, match as few characters as possible in between each pair of `/`s